# Can I read Qur'an from a monitor when I don't have wudu?

Tags: wudu, reading-quran

We don't touch or read Qur'an when we don't have wudu. On the other hand, we can recite it. Which ruling apply to reading Qur'an from a different medium than a printed book? Can we read Qur'an from internet when we don't have wudu, or should we do wudu before we read it through our computers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the wudu requirement is for *mus-hafs* only. A mus-haf is a tangible copy of the Qur'an, something that is permanent. This requirement comes from the ayah in [Surat Waqi'ah:79](http://quran.com/56/79):

> None touch it except the purified.

The scholars say that digital media doesn't count as mus-haf because it is a fleeting display that comes and goes, there is no perpetuity to the display of Qur'an on a screen.

Reference for assertion above: [Answer by Shaykh Salih Munajjid](http://islamqa.com/en/ref/108477/) and from other scholars.

Note this is only about permissibility, not about the etiquette or adab of reciting Qur'an. It is obviously desirable to recite Qur'an in a state of purity from both major and minor hadath (impurities).

Comment: Although, you could call the data that resides on a hard disk just as permanent as being written on paper, just in a different written notation, i.e., binary.

Comment: @Monkieboy maybe the difference is that you don't read the binary, you read a specific rendering of that binary. In any case, this is not my ijtihad.

Comment: @Ansari, one can successfully argue that you do not read the "binary data" (atoms) but rather special molecular formations of ink on a paper :) But yes, that's not your ijtihad.

Comment: Didn't a standard mushaf exist only from the time Caliph Umar(RA)? Did this ruling apply to partial parts of the tangible Quranic notes earlier?

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the same rulings apply as when you read from a paper based Quran. We forget that either way the words of Allah are infront of the reader and deserve the same amount of respect.