# Physical Quran and mobile Quran

Tags: quran

Are there difference in benefits in reading a mobile quran compared to a physical Quran? Due to the nature of my job, I am travelling from site to site. I feel it's more convenient to carry "iQuran". Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quran was never written until after the death of the Prophet PBUH. Thus all the benefits mentioned from the prophet PBUH about reading quran (reward wise) is from reading Quran from Memory. By the rule of inclusion, that means reading it from the book also is considered the same rewards, as well as reading it digitally.

There are some hadiths that give priority to reading from Paper, but according to this [Fatwa](http://islamqa.info/ar/109198) they all are weak.

This is also shown by this [Fatwa](http://islamqa.info/ar/109198) where Shikeh Bin Baz said there is no difference between reading from memory or from a book. The only 2 requirements to get rewards when reading Quran are:

- Your Forethought to be on the Quran (like meditating to Quran).
- Your heart to be into the reading.

If those apply to you when reading the Quran regardless of the medium you will get rewarded In Shaa Allah.

Also according to the following [Fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/106961), you don't need to be purified (wudu) and you can enter the phone into the bathroom OK, since it is a digital pixels and not actual written words on paper.

Comment: The statement *"Quran was never written until after the death of the Prophet PBUH"* is not 100% true, the prophet used to dictate the verses he was revealed each time to his scribs so it was written down on (scattered) papers, a physical copy of the quran (a Moshaf) was not existing at least not an approved one,as some shaba had indeed their (private) quran copys which included verses which have been abrogated before the death of the propeht().

Answer (score 1):

Qur'an was revealed to give guidance to mankind, it was not supposed to be just written on paper. Writing on paper is one means to spread it though. But there are other means too by which it can be spread, like mouth and iQur'an. :)

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have wudu, speak niyat in the heart, and solemnly asking for guidance from Allah SWT, IMO the preparation to read Quran is considered complete

Answer (score 1):

I firmly believe that while one can read Quran in any form but the paper is always preferred. I think the Aya'h that mentions not to touch Quran without wudu is very exclusive to the paper print. As mentioned in the post that digital one can be taken anywhere and touched without wudu.This does not pertain to the actual paper print. May Allah guide me if I put anything wrong

Comment: Salam and welcome on Islam SE. Please consider taking our [tour], checking our [help] and read [answer] to learn how this site is supposed to work. Please consider adding references to support your claims.

Answer (score -1):

Quran is Quran either you read it on mobile or on paper.
I got this by hearing same kind of questions by word on mouth. Somebody asked about how to read Quran on computer. Answer was, you need to do widhu because you can't touch monitor's screen or read it without widhu?

Comment: I dont get your answer please make your little clear please