# Can a woman during menses read the Quran without touching it, or read it from an electronic device?

Tags: quran, taharah, menses

I know that during a girl's period she is not allowed to touch the Quran.

Can she read Quran without touching it, like reciting, or reading from the PC's screen, or mobile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK a muslim (man and woman) is allowed to recite Quran from memory - independent of the state he is in... although there are some opinions stating that if men are in the state of janaabah they need to first make ghusl.

Regarding "women during period" reading it from a screen/mobile etc. there seems to be no "100% consensus"... some say you are allowed, others say you are not... for a detailed analysis see [here](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/2564) and [here](http://islamnewsroom.com/news-we-need/1137-reading-quran-during-monthly-cycle).

Allah knows best.

Comment: Not if he has janaba : Ali Radyallahu'anh said : `` كان رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم لا يحجبه عن قراءة القرآن شيء إلا الجنابة`` which means that nothing prevents the prophet _PBUH_ from reading the Quran but al janaabah. [Source](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=12845)

Comment: @HichamLEMGHARI have you read the sources I linked above ?

Comment: @HichamLEMGHARI Interestingly you say in your answer that it is allowed... rather confusing!

Comment: Sorry I did not read your sources :/; And there is one exception for that : al hayd(Period) because it can last long.

Comment: @HichamLEMGHARI yes... but even for alhayd there different opinions mentioned in those sources...

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, this is a quote from one link I mentioned : ``وذهب بعض العلماء إلى جواز قراءة القرآن للحائض دون الجنب، ومن هؤلاء ابن تيمية -رحمه الله- وهو مذهب مالك، ورواية عن أحمد، وهو أحد قولي الشافعي، وذلك بالاستحسان، لطول مقامها، بخلاف الجنب، فإنه يمكنه رفع حدثه متى شاء.`` The maliki, mazhab is allowing it for example. I have [this link](http://www.ahlalhdeeth.com/vb/showthread.php?t=3028) for you about ``اختلاف العلماء رحمة`` . I wish I made this a little bit more clear :)

Answer (score 1):

in the Hanefi mezheb(most comman concept), you can not recite or read without touching it.It is just like men's impure state, us (men) we can not read or recite Qur'an when we are in that situation. We have to immediately take the ablution. But you can read blessing(words not in the Qur'an).

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we would like to suggest that you read the [FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq). Here we require citations to back up an answer, to make it stronger, and rise it's quality.  Please add some citations to your answer either from a book or from a reliable site, thank you.

Comment: could you plz write your source.

Comment: There is a difference between the situation of men and women. Men can choose to remove this state by taking a shower, whereas women cannot, so the two are not really comparative.

Comment: Source: İbni Mâce, Tahâreh: 105.

Answer (score 1):

#### Reading without touching

[Qur'an 56:79](https://quran.com/56/79) (*none touch it except the purified*) implies that a person in an impure state shouldn't touch the Qur'an<sup>◊</sup>, which includes women during menses.  If she were to not touch the Qur'an, there's a difference of opinion as to whether she may read it, as described by IslamWeb:

> The majority of scholars believe that it is unlawful for the woman, while in her menstruation period, to read the Qur'an. ...
>
> But Imam Malik thinks that it is lawful for her to read it without touching it. This opinion was also reported from Imam Ahmad. It is also one of the opinions of Imam Al Shafi'e. ... We believe that this last opinion is the one most supported by evidence, as mentioned in your question.
>   <sub>[Woman during menses handling Quran](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=86805), IslamWeb</sub>

IslamWeb have other fatawa on this same topic: [Woman during menses handling Quran](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=81639) (*she may look to the Quran and read with her eyes only*), and [Touching Qur'an and praying during menses](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=83772) (*she is allowed to read and review her memorization of the Qur'an without touching it*).

Regarding reciting out loud, [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/2564) states: *The majority of fuqahaa’ say that it is haraam for a woman to recite Qur’aan during her period* (and likewise by [AskImam](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/3938.html)).  See also: [Can a woman recite the Qur'an during her menses?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8598/17163)

#### Touching an electronic version

This boils down to whether an electronically displayed Qur'an is [mushaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mus'haf) and thus necessitates being in a state of wudu to handle.  I found two major opinions on this:

1. They're not mushaf:

   > Mobile phones and other electronic devices in which the Quran is stored are not considered as a Mus-haf (Quran book) and the ruling of a Quran does not apply to them with regard to the obligation of being in a state of ablution to touch it and being disliked to enter the toilet with it and so forth.
   >   <sub>[IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=90896)</sub>

   A fatwa at [fatwa-online.com](http://www.fatwa-online.com/reading-the-quraan-from-a-mobile-phone/) agrees: *There is no harm [in doing so], because it is not a Qur.aan that is in your hands, rather it is a mobile phone.*  Another is at [jamiat.org.za](http://jamiat.org.za/is-wudhu-a-requirement-to-touch-a-cellphone-with-the-quran-installed/).

   IslamWeb likewise considered tafsir and translations of the Qur'an are not considered mushaf and may be touched by women during menses ([ref.](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=91157)) and the same with PDF versions ([ref.](https://fatwa.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=358672)).
2. They're effectively mushaf when Qur'an verses appear on the screen.

   > ... once the verses of the Qur’an appear on the screen, it will not be permitted to touch the area where the actual text appears without Wudu. Touching other parts of the iPhone or device, however, will be permitted.
   >   <sub>[SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2010/07/28/quran-application-on-an-iphone-can-i-touch-my-iphone-without-ablution/), presenting on viewpoint</sub>

   Similar views were given by [Khalifa.com](http://www.khilafah.com/qa-is-it-permissible-for-a-menstruating-woman-to-read-quran-from-the-internet-or-a-mobile-phone/) and [AskImam](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/21492).

See also [Can I read Qur'an from a monitor when I don't have wudu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1235/17163)

---

<sup>◊</sup> [مجاهد's answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/7840/17163) to [Can Qur'an be touched without wudu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2156/17163) gives some nuance to this, but fatawa indicate it's usually considered impermissible, e.g., [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/10672) writes *It is not permissible for a Muslim to touch the Qur’aan when he does not have wudoo, according to the majority of scholars.* Other example fatawa making this same claim are [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=83126), [SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2011/07/31/can-you-touch-partial-verses-of-the-quran-without-wudu/), and [albalagh.net](http://albalagh.net/qa/touching_Quran.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu'Alaikum,

Yes, She can read it (without touching it of course),

You'll find more materials [here](http://ar.islamway.net/fatwa/27886) and [here](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=12845) or on [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGigB61hMzI) (Links in ARABIC)

Allah knows better.