# Can a woman read and recite the Qur'an on a phone during menses?

Tags: halal-haram, reading-quran, menses

I would like to ask since a woman can recite Qur'an while in her menses:

1. Can she read it on her phone, like touching the verses in her phone?
2. Even in her menses does she have to perform wudu before reciting or doing dhikr?

Comment: In regarding to reciting Quran, as far as I serached, seemingly there is no problem in that situation, but apparently it has less thawab ... Good luck.

Comment: Your question can be counted as a really very important and helpful question for women which they should pay attention to its points carefully.

Comment: besides, the following link can be considered as a related issue as well which I suggest you to read it as well. http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8598/can-a-woman-recite-the-quran-during-her-menses/24307#24307

Comment: Ok..but the important thing here is that I asked my question and it was comprehensive enough to be answered...not everybody get a chance to go through all tags,so if someone gets an easy way to learn what they want..then the fast way someone goes

Answer (score 1):

As a general Islamic rule, it would be considered as a haram practice to touch the script of the Holy Qur'an with any part of one's body, without performing Wudhu. But in regards to your second inquiry that you asked

- > 1) Can she read it on her phone,like touching the verses in her phone?

  The response is that touching the Holy Qur'an through cellphones is
  not considered as a haram practice. Since it would be touched
  indirectly. In truth, that is the light/glass of the mobile phone that you
  touch, not the real Quran.

In regards to your second inquiry that you asked

- > “2) Even in her menses does she have to perform wudu before reciting
  >   or doing dhikr?”

  You should pay attention that it is not obligatory (Wajib) to
  perform wudu either. Since the haram practice is touching of Quran
  directly.

Note: As a significant point, when some women is in merses, she should not recite the verses which are Wajib-al-Sajdah (obligatory to Sajdah), even it some Marja'al taqlid declares that she ought no to recite all those Surahs (which have Wajib-al-Sajdah verses). Otherwise you can recite the rest of the holy Quran (except those 4 Surahs according to Shia's perspective)

---

**References:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa4319) and [www.jonbeshnet.ir](http://www.jonbeshnet.ir/news/17367)
- [www.askdin.com](http://www.askdin.com/thread18453.html) and [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa11924)