# To read the Qur'an on a mobile, should I do wudu? Is it complsory?

Tags: quran, wudu, reading-quran, technology

Aslamualikum all.  When we ready the Qur'an as a book, we do wudu.  But when we read it on a mobile, is it compulsory to do wudu? During menses can we read the Qur'an on a mobile?

Comment: [Can we complete quran by reading from book and then from device?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24815/can-we-complete-quran-by-reading-from-book-and-then-from-device) and [Can a woman recite the Qur'an during her menses?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8598/can-a-woman-recite-the-quran-during-her-menses) should answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

It is **not** compulsory or needed to read Qur'an on mobiles with wudu or purity of menses as scholars classify the Qur'an on mobiles (soft copies) to not be related to the rules that apply to the written Qur'an (hard copy).

They explain that the Qur'an on mobiles is just a wave pattern of electrical and magnetic energy vibrating through space and therefore the picture of specific verses appear and goes away once you click on the screen; it is not the same as Mus'haf that a [Sahih Hadith](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/10672/ruling-on-a-person-touching-the-quraan-without-wudoo-and-the-meaning-of-the-hadeeth-the-believer-is-never-impure) has intended it in its narration:

It has been narrated from ‘Amr ibn Hazm stating that the Prophet (Peace Be Upon Him) wrote to the people of Yemen:

> No one should touch the Qur’aan except one who is taahir (pure).

[Mus'haf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mus%27haf) is an Arabic word for a codex or collection of sheets, but also refers to a written copy of the Quran.

According to the definition of Mus'haf, you can notice clearly that it doesn't fit the properties of the Qur'an on mobiles and thus it can't be considered to be a Mus'haf.

---

[Source](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/106961/%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A1%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84-%D9%87%D9%84-%D9%8A%D8%B4%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%B7-%D9%84%D9%87%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B7%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A9)

Answer (score 0):

One of the opinions I know is that whenever you touch the Arabic text of Quran (whether on paper or on screen) you must have wudu.

Comment: Would it be possible to cite where this opinion is from?

Comment: you can search on seekershub.org